# When Url contains non-ASCII charracter i get 404 error (asp.net core + kestler)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-2.2, non-ascii-characters, kestrel

I Have a Multi-Language site , pages would be **redirected** to selected language when user change current language or when users click on the pages links. so passed redirect URL maybe contains **non-ASCII characters**.

I have **`RedirectResultExecutor.cs`** overrided class (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectResultExecutor`) :

```
         /// <param name="result">Redirect result</param>
        /// <returns>Task that represents the asynchronous operation</returns>
        public override Task ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, RedirectResult result)
        {
            if (result == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(result));

            if (_securitySettings.AllowNonAsciiCharactersInHeaders)
            {
                //passed redirect URL contains non-ASCII characters
                result.Url = Uri.EscapeUriString(WebUtility.UrlDecode(result.Url));
            }

            return base.ExecuteAsync(context, result);
        }
```

Error in log :

> Error 404. The requested page
>   (/en/Ã˜Â§Ã˜Â¯Ã™ÂˆÃ˜ÂªÃ™ÂˆÃ›ÂŒÃ™Â„Ã˜Âª-Ã™Â…Ã˜Â±Ã˜Â¯Ã˜Â§Ã™Â†Ã™Â‡-ÃšÂ˜Ã›ÂŒÃ™ÂˆÃ˜Â§Ã™Â†Ã˜Â´Ã›ÂŒ-Ã™Â¾Ã™Â„Ã›ÂŒ-100-Ã™Â…Ã›ÂŒÃ™Â„-2)
>   was not found

**Update:**

I just find out it happens when a URL contains a word like **d`or**

**Update 2**

After not receiving any help or answer i researched and I've found out it's an official issue in asp core 2.2 with **Kestler** :

https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1144

```
//passed redirect URL may contain non-ASCII characters, 
//that are not allowed in kestler so i force to decode and it cause i get weird URL.
result.Url = Uri.EscapeUriString(WebUtility.UrlDecode(result.Url));
```

Any Suggest Would be appreciated :) :)

Comment: don't you guys have any idea? :)

Comment: Could you show your complete log of your request( you could enable logging level to "Debug" in you `appsettings.Development.json` if you use vs.Besides, how does your routing configuration look like?

Comment: @XingZou yes , but it's ourr live website it's a bit hard to debug and checking log for this random error. i will update question if i find any new detail.thank you

Comment: You'd better show the complete log of your request by setting "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    },

Comment: @XingZou it is a random error , but i will try to find it in the log